# How to change picture type of background picture

Tags: excel, vba

I'm parameterizing an Excel chart via OLE. The background picture is set.

```
Sheets.Item['Chart1'].SetBackgroundPicture("ThePicture.jpg")
```

I want to change the Picturetype to stretched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the UserPicture method instead: seems to work (Excel 2003, not tested in other versions).

From Excel VBA Help

UserPicture Method
See AlsoApplies ToExampleSpecificsUserPicture method as it applies to the FillFormat object.

Fills the specified shape with an image.

expression.UserPicture(PictureFile)
expression    Required. An expression that returns one of the above objects.

PictureFile   Required String. The name of the picture file.

UserPicture method as it applies to the ChartFillFormat object.

Fills the specified shape with an image.

expression.UserPicture(PictureFile, PictureFormat, PictureStackUnit, PicturePlacement)
expression    Required. An expression that returns one of the above objects.

PictureFile   Optional Variant.

PictureFormat    Required XlChartPictureType.
XlChartPictureType can be one of these XlChartPictureType constants. 
xlStack 
xlStackScale 
xlStretch

XlChartPictureType can be one of these XlChartPictureType constants. 
xlStack 
xlStackScale 
xlStretch

PictureStackUnit    Required Long. The picture stack or scale unit (depends on the PictureFormat argument).

PicturePlacement    Required XlChartPicturePlacement.

XlChartPicturePlacement can be one of these XlChartPicturePlacement constants. 
xlAllFaces 
xlEnd 
xlEndSides

xlFront

xlFrontEnd

xlFrontSides

xlSides

Example
This example sets the fill format for chart two.

Charts(2).ChartArea.Fill.UserPicture "brick.gif"

Comment: Hello Mr Williams this works! First I had to make the fill visible,         Sheets.Item['Chart1'].ChartArea.Fill.Visible  = True    Thank you very much